# Do fiery blood, Elemental Echo and Shocking flame stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

Only fiery blood says that it adds a +3 feat bonus for fire attacks, but elemental echo and Shocking flame also add damage (provided by feats). I am unsure whther they stack or not. Do they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, they all stack.**

*Fiery Blood* is a feat bonus, which means it does not stack with other feat bonuses. *Elemental Echo* and *Shocking Flame*'s damage bonuses are not feat bonuses, they are untyped bonuses, meaning they stack with everything (including other untyped bonuses).